# (Re-)Align Elements with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, bootsfaces

I've written a little web app, that shows an image and a welcome message to the user. Depending on the device, the text should be side by side with the image or the image should be centered in one line and the text should be centered in another line. The code is in JSF (Bootsfaces) but could also be written in plain HTML.

```html
<b:row>
  <p:graphicImage styleClass="col-md-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm" url="/resources/images/header.png" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;" />
  <p:graphicImage styleClass="center-block visible-xs visible-sm " url="/resources/images/header.png" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;" />
  <!-- header -->
  <div class="col-md-8 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <h:outputText styleClass="h1" value="#{langRes['index.welcomeHeadline']}" escape="false" />
    <p>
      <h:outputText value="#{langRes['index.welcomeText']}" escape="false" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center visible-xs visible-sm">
    <h:outputText styleClass="h1" value="#{langRes['index.welcomeHeadline']}" escape="false" />
    <p>
      <h:outputText value="#{langRes['index.welcomeText']}" escape="false" />
    </p>
  </div>
</b:row>
```

Is it the right approach to hide and show the div's depending on the clients screen size? I don't like the duplication of the image and the text because of DRY. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, then its a Usecase of CSS Media Queries:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3k2r6m4b/ (try to resize the viewport in the Demo or the Browser window to width less/greater than 500px)

The Code Example:

```
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69" class="IMAGE"/>
<div class="TEXT">Text Text Text .......</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.IMAGE{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #BB0000;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.TEXT{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000BB;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .IMAGE{
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    .TEXT{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Media Queries where the right keyword, so I could center the text depending on the screen size!